# Parsing JToken to get Key Value pair

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm getting a feed json from YouTube. I can get the "entry" element and the with:

```
JObject json = JObject.Parse(response);
foreach (var entry in json["feed"]["entry"]) {
            var title = entry["title"];
}
```

But how do I get the Value for 'title'? entry["title].ToString() gives me both key and value as a string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to include the JSON you want to parse in your question.

That being said, going from the feed shown [here](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/standardfeeds/most_popular?v=2&alt=json), which is linked to from the [Developer's Guide: JSON / JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_json), you should do:

```
        foreach (var entry in json["feed"]["entry"])
        {
            var title = (string)entry.SelectToken("title.$t");
        }
```

Comment: To reproduce the json, use this link: https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/[YOUTUBE_USER]/favorites?v=2&alt=json&@&start-index=1&max-results=50